# d3 Uncaught TypeError: n.domain is not a function

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I run this code in my js file and it got an error... like 'Uncaught TypeError: n.domain is not a function'...

```
function drawChart($element,layout,dat){
    console.log(dat);
    var chart_margin = {
        top:10,
        bottom:20,
        left:10,
        right:10
    };

    var height = $element.width()*0.1;
    var width = $element.width();

    $("#est-chart").empty();

    var svg = d3.select('#est-chart').append("svg")
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", height)
        .append("g");

    var y = d3.scaleLinear()
        .domain([0, d3.max(dat, function(d){return d;})])
        .range([0, height]);
    var yAxis = d3.axisLeft(dat);


    var yAxis_g = svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "y axis")
        .call(yAxis);



}
```

Is there anybody can help me with this problem??

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N6Arh.png)

Comment: use Firebug or Developer console to see the callstack

Comment: I just added the capture of error, and it says the function inside d3.min.js is not properly working... but I just download the d3 file from https://d3js.org/.

Comment: for debugging you should use the non-minified version of d3

Comment: Oh.. I changed it to non-minified version, but I still got error with slight change..
Uncaught TypeError: scale.domain is not a function

Comment: what is the error? print-screen it

Comment: I just edited the attached picture on the original post!

Comment: did you include 'd3-scale'?

Comment: I thought scale is included in the D3.js....

Comment: it seems it is not

Comment: How can I include 'd3-scale'...?

Comment: How did you included  d3.js?

Comment: `<script src="https://d3js.org/d3-scale.v1.min.js"></script>`

Comment: I downloaded the d3.zip from d3js.org(there is nothing like d3-scale...), extract it and move d3.js to my desired location.

Comment: I got new errors.. I think it needs more files like d3-array.js, d3-collection.js, d3-interpolate.js, d3-format.js, d3-time.js, d3-time-format.js, d3-color.js.

Comment: I think you have a typo in the last line of your code. It should be `.call(Axis);` instead of `.call(yAxis);`

Comment: @Marcelo Why It should be Axis instead of yAxis??
I tried 'Axis' and it gives an error like 'Uncaught ReferenceError: Axis is not defined'. I think it's because there is no variable with name Axis. Am I right??

Comment: @SeungyeonWoo The post was edited. The first post had Axis as the variable name. Here is an updated [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/svg3fLb5/1/)

Comment: @Marcelo oh... I really appreciate your effort. It finally works!!
Thank you so much!!!

Comment: @Marcelo But in my result the number on the scale doesn't appear, my chart only has a scale , no numbers..... Is it related to 
var yAxis = d3.axisLeft(dat).scale(y);
this part??

Comment: @SeungyeonWoo Yes, you need an scale in order to know how to drawn the numbers

Answer (score 0):

There is a typo change Axis to yAxis and try...

```
yAxis = d3.axisLeft(dat);
```

Comment: sorry.. I deleted some words while posting.. Thank you for letting me know I changed the code

Comment: can you share a fiddle?